# writer.writerow() is not working inside the for loop to write all specific data

Tags: python, csv

My script get address from the address_array and search that address and collect specific data against it one by one, My script is run fine but problem is in `writer.writerow()`. Its not writing the multiple data in to the `save_data.csv`.  I really appreciate it if someone help me.

```
import csv
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

initRow = 0
with open('Search.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    with open('save_data.csv', 'a') as f:
        fieldnames = ["Address", "Name", "Mailing Address", "Ph"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        # DictReader class basically creates a CSV object that behaves like a Python OrderedDict
        address_array = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            address = row['Address'].split(',')
            address_array.append(address)
        print(address_array)

        indexes = 0
        # search_address = input(" Copy Address from Excel file and paste here \n")
        # print(search_address)
        for j in range(initRow, len(address_array)):
            # res1 = any(search_address in sublist for sublist in address_array)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
            driver.get('somesite') 
            sleep(7)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-address"]').send_keys(address_array[j])
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/input[3]').click()
            sleep(10)
            try:
                address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div').text
                name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('owner-name').text
                mailing_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div').text
                phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/strong').text
              #  line = [[address, owner_name, mailing_address, opa_account]]
            except:
                pass
            writer.writerow({"Address": address, "Name": name, "Mailing Address": mailing_address,  
                             "Ph": phone})

            print(address,name, mailing_address, phone)
            print('---------------------------')
            print('---------------------------')

            driver.quit()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you skip `writerow()` in case of exception? Also you are trying to write a dict with key `Phone`, but you mentioned `Ph` in fieldnames

Comment: I have corrected the fieldname it was typing mistake ...Would you please suggest me the solution how to write data one by one in save_data.csv file.

Comment: you say its not writting the multiple data in the file. Well what is it doing then

Comment: no data is writing in to the file  .
 but if I do single search without using loop  single data successfully written in to file.

Comment: What is the output of `print(address,name, mailing_address, phone)` in that case?

Comment: add a simple print inside your loop to be sure your loop is printing ot like @kuro said, print the values of your varaibles in each iteration to see if your loop is actually running as you expect

Comment: yes print statement show exactly what I want .. but somehow not writing into the file.

Comment: print statement working fine , its shows all data one by one correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> try it like make a list and append all data in that list then write in csv

```
datalist=[]
datalist.append([address, name, mailing_address,phone])

then write data in csv 
writer.writerow(('address', 'name', 'mailing_address','phone'))
writer.writerows(datalist)
```

Comment: writerows() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given , this error occur

Comment: > try it like make a list and append all data in that list then write in csv 

```
datalist=[]
datalist.append([address, name, mailing_address,phone])

then write data in csv 
writer.writerow(('address', 'name', 'mailing_address','phone'))
writer.writerows(datalist)

```

Comment: wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys' its showing this error

Comment: are you there ? I have a question. When I closed the browser forcefully the data write in to the file. otherwise its null